# Dynamic Table Destination Invokes "Not Found" Errors

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Since at least 2.13.0, the Python SDK for Apache-Beam has supported dynamic BigQuery table destinations determined at run-time for the `beam.io.WriteToBigQuery` class if the `--experiments=use_beam_bq_sink` flag is set.

[Two ways of implementing](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.13.0/apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery.html#writing-data-to-bigquery) this are with a side input, or a callable that returns the table name. For example:

```py
def table_name_gen(row):
    return 'project:dataset.test$' + row['Date']

out_to_bq = elements | 'out to bq' >> beam.io.WriteToBigquery(
    table=table_name_gen,
    schema=schema,
    create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
    write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE
)
```

This successfully generates the correct table name. However, what beam seems to do is create a temporary beam load table, and then tries to do a copy job from that table to the destination table.

It creates a table with a name like:

`project:dataset.beam_load_2019_11_13_163621_86_b3183c21100a4a635d96159f63af7bdc_1573662983`

However, when it then goes to copy from this table, it returns an error:

```
message: 'Not found: Table project:dataset.beam_load_2019_11_13_163621_86_b3183c21100a4a635d96159f63af7bdc_1573662983 was not found in location EU'
```

This is incorrect, as I can see the table in the BigQuery UI. Is Beam trying to copy from the table before it's finished being created? Anyone know how to solve this? Not only that but once the job fails, those temporary tables still exist; and it is confusing to me why they exist in the first place when batch job method defaults to FILE_LOAD; it should be staging the data in GCS.

addendum: Inspecting the code [here](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.16.0/_modules/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.html#WriteToBigQuery) and [here](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.16.0/_modules/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery_file_loads.html) indicates that beam creates temp files in the staging/temp area, then loads those into temporary tables in BQ and then copies from those tables to the actual destination table, and then deletes the temporary tables. Because the job fails the temporary tables aren't deleted. Because they're successfully created, but the subsequent copy job fails, I'm at a loss to what's actually breaking here.

Comment: Where is the dataset located? Is it using a regional or multi-regional [location](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/locations?hl=es-419)?

Comment: @GuillemXercavins the dataset is located in the EU - multi-regional

Comment: @GuillemXercavins as a test I created a new dataset and staging bucket that were regional in europe-west2 and received the same error.

Comment: Does it work without the partition decorator `$`? I did not get your error with any of my previous runs but I didn't use partitioned tables

Comment: I haven't tried without the partition decorator yet. Digging through the stackdriver logs, it seems like Dataflow successfully creates an insert job which stages the data in the temporary table, but then doesn't wait for it to finish. The insert job in my test run finished at 9:21:31 and Dataflow triggered a copy job to start at 9:20:58, 4 seconds after the insert job had started, and before it finished. I've opened a case with Google support and can add an answer here when they resolve, unless someone knows another fix.

Comment: @Daniel thanks for catching the issue. This is a bug with the code to create jobs - you're right that Dataflow is not waiting for the jobs as it should - this should be resolved in the next version of Beam (2.17, I believe).

Comment: that should fix the error that you're seeing..

Comment: Any update on this, do you have an idea if the bug was fixed? Thanks

Comment: @ECris this is still an issue. It will supposedly be fixed in the next beam release (2.17, current is 2.16), but that hasn't come out yet.

Comment: @Daniel, I saw 2.17 was released recently and couldn't find this bug in the release notes. Thought I'd ask.